# Remove space above and below <p> tag HTML

Tags: html, css

Take this `ul` for example:

```html
<ul>
    <li>HI THERE</li>
    <br>
    <li>
        <p>ME</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the innerHtml of an `li` tag is blank, the `li` wraps itself right up to the text.

It doesn't happen for the `p` tag. I'm assuming this is because `p` is for paragraphs which usually have white space breaks before and after.

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: What's with that `<br>`, by the way?

Comment: are you asking how to remove whitespace from the source code view, or how to remove padding and space from the visual output of the browser?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`<p>` elements generally have [margins and / or padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#mpb-examples). You can set those to zero in a stylesheet.

```
li p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Semantically speaking, however, it is fairly unusual to have a list of paragraphs.

Comment: I'm only using P so i can give it an id. What would you recommend. I avoiding using divs as I already have too many.

Comment: Li and Ul seem to have default margins and padding too. Thank you so much. This saved me a world of trouble!

Comment: It depends why you want to give it an id. You could give the `<li>` an id.

Comment: Or you could use a `<span>` instead of a `<p>` to add that Id :)

Comment: That didn't work for me. I needed to add `display` property with `inline` value: `display: inline ;` to the CSS (without `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`) to get it working.

Comment: @S.Goswami — Then something else was interfering. All else being equal, this will work.

Answer (score 14):

Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp

> The p element automatically creates some space before and after
>   itself. The space is automatically applied by the browser, or you can
>   specify it in a style sheet.

you could remove the extra space by using css

```
p {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

or use the element `<span>` which has no default margins and is an inline element.

Comment: Please don't misattribute the work of the [dreadful](http://w3fools.com/) W3Schools to the W3C.

Comment: I'm sorry! Edited my post ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone wishes to do this with bootstrap, version 4 offers the following:

> The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs
>   and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.

Where property is one of:

```
m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding
```

Where sides is one of:

```
t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
```

Where size is one of:

```
0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
```

For example:

```
.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.ml-1 {
  margin-left: ($spacer * .25) !important;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: ($spacer * .5) !important;
  padding-right: ($spacer * .5) !important;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: $spacer !important;
}
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways:

The best way is to remove the `<p>` altogether. It is acting according to specification when it adds space.

Alternately, use CSS to style the `<p>`. Something like:

```
ul li p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS Reset is best way to use for this issue. Right now in reset we are using p and in need bases you can add any number of tags by come separated.

```
p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags have built in padding and margin.  You could create a CSS selector combined with some javascript for instances when your `<p>` is empty.  Probably overkill, but it should do what you need it to do.

CSS example: `.NoPaddingOrMargin {padding: 0px; margin:0px}`

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. If you want to use a CSS class *selector* to select an element with an HTML class, then it needs to start with a `.` and should have a name that describes *what* the element represents and not how it should look.

Answer (score -1):

I don't why you would put a`<p>`element there.
But another way of removing spaces in between the paragraphs is by declaring only one paragraph

```
<ul>
   <p><li>HI THERE</li>
    <br>
    <li>ME</li>
     </p>
   </ul>
```

Comment: That is invalid HTML and gets horrible mangled when the browser tries to parse it.