# Extra Space After Paragraph Tags

Tags: html, wordpress

Is there a way to use the (`<p></p>`) tags without the extra space on the lines before and after the phrase? I'm using them on wordpress.com.

I'm trying to add a background color to some lines but they need to be in `<p></p>` tags so an extra space is not created between the lines.

Is there a non CSS solution? I can't modify the the CSS at the moment.

Comment: have you tried: p{margin:0}

Comment: Absolutely! `p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove space above and below <p> tag HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874402/remove-space-above-and-below-p-tag-html)

Comment: Have you got an example? It sounds like margin is overwriting what you've tried somewhere

Comment: are those css solutions?

Comment: @Itay Grudev please don't edit like that, the question loses it's meaning, OP specifically says that he doesn't want CSS solution, and you are removing that line out of the question

Comment: Sounds like you need this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-p/

Comment: @Paulie_D not exactly. VBA wants to use the `<p>` tags but without the default padding.

Comment: @Mr.Alien That only happened because that line was added before my change but after I was already on the edit page. I did not removed it.

Comment: @VBAProgrammer even if you can't modify any pre-existing CSS files, you can insert your own style tags at any time (even if inline and by javascript), or you could assign style attributes with the respective content.

Comment: @JanDvorak how do I do that?

Comment: @HashemQolami where do i add that line of code? in the CSS?

Comment: @VBAProgrammer look up `createElement` and `appendChild` on MDN. With jQuery, `append` or `appendTo`.

Comment: @VBAProgrammer First of all, I suggest to read [this topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do) and check *The legendary* [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). However, you should use these CSS declarations to reset the **user agent stylesheet** at the very beginning of the **author stylesheet** (Your own CSS file, or Your internal `<style>` element.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove the padding & margin on p elements without the usage of css.

The easiest way to override the fact that you cant add a class or change it in a css file is to add it directly to the p element. This is not valid HTML5 though and should be avoided as much as possible.

Try this out:

```
<p style="margin: 0;">Text</p>
```

You can add other styling elements within the style tag too. Things like background colors, padding, etc.

Just remember to avoid using this way it when possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
p{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: is this a css solution?

Comment: @VBAProgrammer yes it is a CSS solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the default margins you can use:

```
p {
margin:0;
}
```

However for future reference you may want to use a styles reset to prevent the default margins and paddings from being added. Then you can specify how much of a margin and padding to use. Here's a commmonly used style reset:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without CSS, then you can do it in jQuery or JavaScript

### jQuery

```
      $('p').css('margin','0');
```

or

### JavaScript

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('p').style.margin = '0';
```

You can do it either way.