# How to add click on mat label in mat stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

I need a click functionality on matSteplabel. Added click on mat-step also but no use!

```
                  <ng-template (click)="myFunc()" matStepLabel>

                    Snapshot

                  </ng-template>
                  <!-- Start All Backup Data Step1 Data -->

                       <!--app-compare-data-step1></app-compare-data-step1-->

                  <!-- End All Backup Data Step1 Data -->


                </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: You need to add your full code sample, this doesn't look like it should compile currently.

Comment: I added but it was taken half code. How to edit?

Comment: <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" [selectedIndex]="1" editable="false" #stepper>
                    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">

                      <ng-template (click)="myFunc()" matStepLabel>
                        
                        Snapshot

                      </ng-template>
                    </mat-step>

                    </mat-horizontal-stepper>

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `ng-template` wrong. Ng-template is just a wrapper and it's the content of it that will be appended to the element referencing it.

Whatever you define on `ng-template` tag accept for the name will be lost.
So you have to define your `click` somewhere inside the `ng-template`'s body and not on the tag itself.

Answer (score -1):

As [Miroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160985/miroslav-jonas) mentioned you can use something like this:

```
<ng-template matStepLabel>

               <p (click)="myFunc()">Snapshot</P>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: I am still looking for a way to have a click on mat-step-header. If I attach a click handler to a <p> element inside ng-template , only works if I click on <p> but I cannot make <p> fill all the space of the container. I am using mat-vertical-stepper

Comment: Try some css. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874402/remove-space-above-and-below-p-tag-html

Comment: @Gringo check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910602/8662476