# How to bind an click event for mat-step-header

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to trigger a function when user clicks on `mat-step-header`

I've tried adding `(click)` on `<ng-template matStepLabel><span (click)="triggerClick()">step 1</span></ng-template>`
but it's triggering only on the click of `label` which will not be helpful for my case.

I want to trigger a function when user click on any of the `mat-step-header` if it returns the index of clicked step it will be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Probably you have solved it now, but just in case anyone else is seeking for a simple solution:

Simply put an overlay `<div>` on top of the stepper header like this below:

```html
<ng-template matStepLabel>
  <div class="stepper-header-overlay" (click)="yourClickHandler()"></div>
  some header text
</ng-template>
```

And setup the header style:

```css
.stepper-header-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why not use `selectionChange` Output of the mat-stepper? else if you use keyboard to move between steppers don't work

Comment: @Eliseo the goal isn't to fire the event when step changes. It is to fire the event when the stepper header is clicked. It could be to display an error message when navigation is impossible

Comment: works nice. It is a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

From the docs it doesn't look like there's a direct way to do this. The only `eventEmitter` that could help you would be `selectionChange()`. We can use this along with a `(click)` event to get the `selectedIndex` on click.

We can use `selectionChange()` to get the index of the selected tab. As per the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepper)

> `selectionChange()` is the event emitted when the selected step has changed

In your HTML

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper (selectionChange)="setIndex($event)" (click)="triggerClick($event)">
  <!-- Add your steppers here -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and in your component

```js
// Set default tab value to index so you don't get undefined if user clicks default tab initially
selectedIndex: number = 0;

setIndex(event) {
  this.selectedIndex = event.selectedIndex;
}

triggerClick(event) {
  console.log(`Selected tab index: ${this.selectedIndex}`);
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-click).

Comment: This will trigger only when stepper changes, but i want to trigger an function on click on `mat-step-header`. The above solution will not help in solving my problem.

Comment: This does exactly what you asked for though. When you click on the ````mat-step-header````, it returns the index of the selected ````mat-step-header````. What exactly is your use case? What do you want to do on click of the ````mat-step-header````?

Comment: If i'm not wrong the above code will trigger on change/select of step. But i need something when user click on `step-header` my function should trigger.

Answer (score 2):

In your component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('stepper', {static: false})
stepper: MatStepper;

constructor(
  private elementRef: ElementRef,
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mat-step-header').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      const index = event.currentTarget.ariaPosInSet - 1;

     });
  });
}
```

I know it's not elegant, but it works. Any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

(selectionChange) event triggered after stepper change, want to call function before selectionChange.

Below code working for me, Try this it will work for entire mat-step button (because of custom css, you can add css for span too).

you have to write this for every mat-step if you want to call function on each mat-step.

```
.mat-step-custom-click {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 130px; // as per your need
    height: 72px; // as per your need
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div class="mat-step-custom-click" (click)="justTesting()">
            <span>YOUR LABEL</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>


justTesting(){
   if( stepper.selectedIndex ){ // you can check stepper index
      let isValid = this.CheckValidations(yourData); // check your validations
      stepper.selected.completed = isValid;
      if( isValid ){
       doSomething(); // call your function
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice; though you can just add an empty div at the top of the stepLabel to preserve the default styling on the contents.

Answer (score -1):

You can add (click) on the mat-step-header for sure

```
<mat-step-header  class="mat-vertical-stepper-header"(click)="step.select()"
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the complete structure? because i have not used <mat-step-header in my stepper template i have used  `<ng-template matStepLabel>`

Comment: In that case you can do something like this https://github.com/bdimir/swedbankHw/blob/b7d65ad2d11870926272cfcbd8198508d175a502/src/app/modules/loans/components/small-loan/small-loan.component.html

Comment: I have tried the solution but it is not helping for my use case.